# Why does `gsub!` return `nil`?

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I am using a hash map to advance the character by position: `"a"` into `"b"`, etc., and to capitalize vowels.

```
def LetterChanges(str)
  str.to_s
  puts str
  h = ("a".."z").to_a
  i = ("b".."z").to_a.push("a")
  hash = Hash[h.zip i]
  new_str = str.downcase.gsub(/[a-z]/,hash)
  new_str.gsub!(/[aeiou]/) {|n| n.upcase }
end

LetterChanges("hello world")
LetterChanges("sentence")
LetterChanges("replace!*")
LetterChanges("coderbyte")
LetterChanges("beautiful^")
LetterChanges("oxford")
LetterChanges("123456789ae")
LetterChanges("this long cake@&")
LetterChanges("a b c dee")
LetterChanges("a confusing /:sentence:/[ this is not!!!!!!!~")
```

The above code works as expected except for the examples `"replace!*"` and `"123456789ae"`, for which it returns `nil`.  Why is this?

Comment: I am still not sure why but, I was able to get the expected result by changing the the second gsub to scan.

Comment: `str.tr("a-z", "bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzA")`

Comment: "Why does `gsub!` return `nil`?" - it is __specifically mentioned__ in the documentation.

Answer (score 10):

[`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) modifies the original string, and returns that string *or nil if no replacements were performed*.

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) does not modify the original string but always return the result even if nothing was changed.

Either return `new_str` at the end of your method, or use `gsub` instead of `gsub!`.

This is somewhat of a pattern in Ruby - when multiple version of a method exist, the one with `!` will modify the receiver and the one without will simply return the result.

As an aside, it looks like you're not using the result of `str.to_s` for anything. If you know it's a string, `to_s` is pointless. If it might not be, you should make use of the result, for example like so:

```
str = str.to_s
```

Answer (score 3):

[`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) returns `nil` when no substitution is performed.

```
new_str.gsub!(/[aeiou]/) {|n| n.upcase }
```

returns `nil` when `new_str` doesn't contain any vowel letters. This is the case for example, if `str` is `"replace!*"`, `new_str` is `sfqmbdf!*`, no vowels.